# Availability Alert root cause

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-availability-set

I have an web app set up on Azure. 
I have received an availability alert for my web app. i found that when the availability was down, at the same time the CPU usage went high to 100% and due to this, the application pool might have restarted causing the availability alert.
How can I see which request cause the CPU to went high so that i can check the request. 
I know we can do this running the profiling for a specific time, but in this case, the incident is already occurred, and can not be reproducible

Comment: I doubt you can see what request *caused* anything. Correlation between timestamps is probably as good as its gonne get.

Answer (score 0):

@Umesh, if you are using Application Insights with your webapp, please use the "Search" blade to figure out what requests were sent to your application:

[image]

Hope this helps!